# Save DataTable to database as a file

Tags: c#, sql, file, datatable

I have a DataTable, `dt` that I want to email to a user as a CSV file.  The existing emailing workflow involves adding the file to an `attachments` table and then the emailing function will pull the file from there.  For now, I'm bypassing teh email part and downloading the file directly using the ID and a function that works for all the other files in the table (which includes csv and xls).  The problem is that everything I've tried for adding the DataTable as a file to this table will be downloaded as random Unicode characters.

What I've tried:

- Convert DataTable to CSV string and use `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(attachmentCSV)` to make a `byte[]`
- Create a MemoryStream as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20512512/1618257)
- Combinations of the previous 2

I'm not finding anything else helpful through my searching, so I'm at a loss at what to try next.  How can I take a DataTable and save it into a SQL table as a file (csv, xls, any spreadsheet format that Excel will open)?  Ideally, I'd like a way that avoids saving the file to disk first.

Comment: Your first attempt is what you should do, but we can't help because we don't know what `attachmentCSV` is or how you are attaching this to an email.

Comment: @DavidG `attachmentCSV` is just a string variable that's the DataTable converted to CSV.  The email isn't the problem at the moment, since I'm bypassing that part and downloading directly with the ID (a method that works for all other files in the table).

Comment: In your post, you said 'and downloading the file directly using the ID and a function that works for all the other files in the table (which includes csv and xls)'. If the function already works for the other CSVs, how are those CSVs getting uploaded?

Comment: @RyanCarlisle They are uploaded by a user.  This is the first instance I've seen of trying to create the file from a DataTable without downloading and then uploading

Comment: @DavidStarkey Do you have access to how the upload process works at current-state? If so, you should be able to see how the file is uploaded and then create a CSV file from your CSV String and upload it the same way.

Comment: @RyanCarlisle It uses a `HttpPostedFileBase` with jquery.fileupload

Comment: Glad you figured it out.

Comment: I would send as an xml which is a little more robust and easy to convert back to a datatable.  You can include a schema in the xml so you can get back the same types as original table.

Comment: @jdweng Good suggestion.  For this specific example I'm not interested in what happens after it is emailed.  There is no uploading it or anything, it's just for emailing a group of users some information in a table format.

Answer (score 1):

This problem lies in the software being used to open the file, LibreOffice.  The character set was being set to UTF-16 instead of UTF-8.  Changing the set appears to fix the problem.